# Python replace multiple string patterns in column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe of multiple movies containing synopsis.

```
Title        Synopsis
Movie1       Old Macdonald had a farm         [Written by ABC rewrite] 
Movie2       Wheels on the bus                 (Source: Melon)
Movie3       Tayo the bus                      [Produced by Wills Garage]
Movie4       James and Giant Apple             (Source: Kismet)
```

I'd like to remove the trailing words that are not required for NLP such that I get a dataframe below

```
Title        Synopsis
Movie1       Old Macdonald had a farm         
Movie2       Wheels on the bus                
Movie3       Tayo the bus                      
Movie4       James and Giant Apple
```

I've tried the following code but my synopsis column ends up with some string like "0"Iodfosomhgooad,somh...\n1GaBauadFal..." Was wondering if how i could resolve this, appreciate any form of help, thank you.

```
removelist = [('[Written by]', '') ,('(Source:)', '')]
               
for old, new in removelist:
    df['Synopsis'] = re.sub(old, new, str(df['Synopsis']))
```

Comment: Are those un-necessary data is present in every row?

Comment: @RishabhKumar, not necessarily, the unnecessary data can appear in any row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['Synopsis'] = df['Synopsis'].str.replace(r'\s*(?:\[[^][]*]|\([^()]*\))\s*$', '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8UxDnr/1).

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:\[[^][]*]|\([^()]*\))` - either

  - `\[[^][]*]` - a `[`, any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` char
  - `|` - or
  - `\([^()]*\)` - a `(`, any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex replace method directly available to strings in Pandas DataFrames.

```py
data['Synopsis'] = data['Synopsis'].str.replace('\[.*\]$|\(.*\)$','', regex=True)
```

match anything between [] at end of string

\[.*\]$

multiple string patterns

|

match anything between () at end of string

\(.*\)$

The result of your sample is:

```py
                         Synopsis
Title                            
Movie1  Old Macdonald had a farm 
Movie2         Wheels on the bus 
Movie3              Tayo the bus 
Movie4     James and Giant Apple
```

Comment: I upvoted, not sure who downvoted though.